# How to get the latest value with best SQL performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a table A with two columns: datetime and value. Table A is a huge one with tens of million data inside.

In my SQL statement (in mysql dialet), I wanna

1) fetch the latest value (value with latest datetime)

2) fetch values in the range a timespan

My current solution

1)

```
SELECT value
FROM A
WHERE datetime = (
    SELECT MAX(datetime)
    FROM A
    ORDER BY datetime
);
```

2)

```
SELECT value
FROM A
WHERE datetime IN (
    SELECT datetime
    FROM A
    WHERE datetime > start_time AND datetime < finish_time
);
```

However, I doubt this is a optimized solution because of the inner SELECT.

Is there better way to achieve this with better performance?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1)

```
SELECT value FROM A ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1
```

2)

```
SELECT value FROM A 
   WHERE datetime > :start_time AND datetime < :finish_time
```

**And (most importantly!) you want an index on datetime.**

Comment: It is actually a smart idea to use a compound index (datetime,value) in this case.  That means your queries can be entirely satisfied from the index.

Comment: If the range is long, yes. If not, it seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: Why do I need a compound index, wherein also value is also included? When the condition is only datetime?

Comment: You do not *need* a compound index (or any index), but it would increase performance. A compound index with all fields that you need could satisfy the query without touching the table at all. With only `datetime`, you still have to access the table after going through the index (which should be okay, unless the selected range is huge).